# Counting fields within an array in mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongoose, count, field

I want to do summation on an array. This the model

```
modelDetail.aggregate([
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$main_section.first_name',  
                    count: {$sum: 'first_array.second_array.field_name'}
                }
            }
        ], function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    //next(err);
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                    res.json(result);
                }
        });
```

This is bringing out 0 for all the result. Output is below

```
[{"_id":"first","count":0},
{"_id":"second","count":0},
{"_id":"third","count":0},
{"_id":"Fourth","count":0},
{"_id":"Fifth","count":0},// i expected 8 here
{"_id":"Sixth","count":0},
{"_id":"Seventh","count":0},// i expected 5 here
{"_id":"Eigth","count":0},// i expected 3 here
{"_id":"Ninth","count":0}]
```

I wanted to get the count of all the data this is my schema

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    main_section        :{
        first_name          : String
    },

    first_Array :[{//1st level
        array_info          : String,
        second_array            :[{//2nd level
            detail1             : String,//3rd level
            field_name          : String
        }]
    }]
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You say you "expected" different results in some cases. How would you prove or disprove those expectations? What debugging have you tried? Show your research in the text of the question.

Comment: This is the data that already exist in mongodb. that is the reason why i said i expected different results

Comment: How would you test your assertions? You are logging in one place. How would you work from the known to the unknown? Is that schema correct? Is mongodb case sensitive?

Comment: I already have the data in my mongodb database which I can see through cli. Also the schema is correct. I beleive if the schema is not correct the database would not have been created, or do you think it would? Please I am still new to this thing so pardon me if I make any mistake. About case sensitive I do not think I set i to be case sensitive.

Comment: Is the mongodb schema case-sensitive? (I don't know, but I suspect yes.) What does `sum` do if you refer to schema objects that are not present? (What if it just ignores missing schema refs, perhaps because the case is wrong?) Creating is different from selecting, right? Rule out the obvious by working from the known to the unknown.

Comment: The OP should feel free to [edit] this question and be sure to show the _exact_ code run to get these results.